# Is this a bug to report in VS Code or in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Given the following code:

```js
if (<number>foo < <number>bar) {
}
```

The `foo` and `bar` variables are both of type `any` (they're deserialised from JSON) and the intention above is to cast them to type `<number>` before comparing them.

If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> in VS-code to reformat the source which contains this statement, it becomes ...

```js
if (<number>foo <<number>bar) {
}
```

... which no longer compiles.

I guess this is a bug -- where should I report it?

Is the bug in VS Code, or is it in TypeScript, or is it in some VS Code extension for TypeScript?

Comment: Note that a type assertion is *not* a cast; TS doesn't exist at runtime. What's the specific error when it doesn't compile?

Comment: Formatting from vscode is done by the Ts language service as far as i know. You can report it on the VS Code GH issue tracker and they will move it to ts if it is not in the right repo.

Comment: I think this is a bug as well. For the moment you can use `if((foo as number) < (bar as number))` as a workaround. But like what jonrsharpe said, if `foo` and `bar` are of the type `any` then you really can just simply write `if(foo < bar)` and it makes zero difference.

Comment: @Mu-TsunTsai or ideally it is to not use either of those and just type the values properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report

Answer (score 0):

It is best to try on a fresh Visual Studio Code instance, and if it happens then, go report it.

Comment: The question was, where to report it: so are you saying it's a VS-code bug?

Comment: Nope.. I am saying if this happens on a brand new Visual Studio Code without any extensions, then we can consider it as a bug. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?template=bug_report.md

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments.

I submitted it as a VS-code bug -- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/75986